# Input box width computed sizing issue - mobile safari (ipad)

Tags: html, ios, css

First post. I've searched long and hard for a solution without success.

I have a web page that incorporates an input text box inside a table cell. The table is fixed layout with explicit col widths (160px) in a colgroup tag. The box is size=22 with font size = 9pt.

In pc safari or chrome etc, the box has a computed size = 147px.
In mobile safari (v6), the box has a computed size = 178px.

Does anybody know how i can make ios compute the box the same size as a desktop browser?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: you could try `box-sizing: border-box;` it usually helps with inconsistencies similar to this.

Comment: Maybe it could be solved by setting the display value to inline-block or trying a different box-sizing option(edit as the commenter above says)  (border-box, content-box), sounds like it's got to be something like that.

Comment: Thanks guys. Tried these but no difference.

Comment: Update - managed to fudge it. Found that defining the size of the input box in pixels in the html worked. So: style='width:150px;'